# Validating values below 100 and between 1 and 5

Tags: python, validation, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe that I have to validate with PySpark. One of the columns can only accept values from 0 to 100, and I have another column that only accepts values from 1 to 5. What would be the right approach to validate that information? Ideally, the program should crash if it fails indicating the error.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I would simply filter for rows that violate the conditions and then assert that there are none:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=1, b=1),
    Row(a=6, b=101),
])

rows_with_issues = \
    df.where(~F.col('a').between(1,5) | ~F.col('b').between(0,100))

n_rows_with_issues = rows_with_issues.count()
if n_rows_with_issues > 0:
    raise Exception(
        f'The {n_rows_with_issues} rows violate the data constraints. Showing five rows:\n'
        '\n'.join([str(r) for r in rows_with_issues.take(5)])
    )
```

Such a test is expensive for larger data sets, however, because all the data have to be processed.

Comment: I think you should add checks for null values too.